# How to tee to possible new files

Tags: shell, sh

I am making a script that needs to tee some output lines from another script to multiple files
The idea is to make something like attachable listeners
The problem is, some files aren't know on startup, more files could be created to receive the data

For example:

```sh
# using yes instead of the actual script
yes | tee listeners/* >> /dev/null &
touch listeners/a
```

tee will pipe to the files already on the folder, but never to `a`

I could make a while read loop to start tee after every line, but that makes it much slower
Is there any other way to do it? Even another design for that?

Comment: When you specify baseline `sh`, do you also mean to imply that you need portability to systems with only POSIX-specified tools? Any reasonable implementation will require `inotifywait` or an equivalent tool to use your operating system's facilities to provide a notification whenever directory contents change (and honestly, trying to implement this in shell is not a great idea at all).

Comment: ...anyhow, as a starting point, if I were trying to implement this in bash on Linux, I'd have `inotifywait` sending a signal to a process that trips a flag (see the shell `trap` mechanism) that tells it to re-open the copy of `tee` it copies contents to (see the use of `exec` to replace file descriptors in-place, and `>(...)` for process substitution), generating a new instance with a freshly-evaluated glob.

Comment: Honestly, though, if I were implementing this myself, I wouldn't do it in shell. Go, or Python, or even C are much better choices.

Comment: Yep, i need it to be portable, `inotifywait` would be a problem as i use FreeBSD...
Maybe i should go with the slow loop way if there is no better choice, but as the rest of the project is already on shell script, i would need this part to be shell as well

Comment: Frankly, if the alternative is running `tee` once per line, you'd be better off reimplementing `tee` natively in shell so you aren't eating process startup overhead every single message. The shell is slow to read input (it reads one byte at a time so as not to consume more of the stream), but starting an external command over and over is *slower*, by far.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do for f in listeners/*; do printf '%s\n' "$line" >"$f"; done; done` is fugly and slow, but it's better than the repeated-single-line-tee approach.

Comment: ...that said, do you have a specific time window in which a listener needs to start receiving new events? If you used a signal to time glob reevaluations, that would help in high-throughput cases, at a cost to startup latency. (Granted, rotating the FIFO without unfortunate boundary cases is a problem all its own, and deciding how best to handle it would require more information on where the events are *coming from*, who controls that code, etc).

Comment: Oh, and another note -- `inotifywait` [**is** available on FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=inotifywait&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports). So is bash (and other shells that have adopted ksh features like process substitution), for that matter.

Comment: I see, for sake of simplicity, maybe i should try `inotifywait` before glob reevaluations

Comment: You still need to reevaluate the glob after the list of files changes; inotifywait just tells you *when to do that*, so you aren't doing it every single line, and can leave each `tee` process running longer.

Comment: I am trying that now, but how could i make the `inotifywait` loop change the tee?
Like, should i kill the tee process and start another with the glob reevaluated?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Charles Duffy comments, i made something like this:

```sh
rm -f pipe && mkfifo pipe
script > pipe &

rm -f pid
inotifywait -m -e create -e delete listeners/ --format '%f' \
| (while read -r file; do
       [ -f pid ] && kill "$(cat pid)"
       cat pipe | tee listeners/* >> /dev/null &
       echo "$(jobs -p)" > pid
   done)
```

It's really faster than the while read loop, and uses little to no CPU